# Blank window when using Qt with ANGLE on Win 7

Tags: windows, qt, opengl-es, qtquick2

I have a Qt Quick 2 app (QML) that is showing a blank window on certain Windows PCs. Any ideas how to cure this?

I am aware that the need for Qt Quick 2 to use OpenGL 2.0 has caused issues like this on some Windows PCs, particularly ones with Intel graphics cards. The solution I have adopted is to force the use of ANGLE when compiling for Windows. This has been very successful, except for a couple of PCs, which display a blank window (usually white) and fail to redraw if you switch away and switch back to the application.

Below is a short test app that demonstrates the problem. When running correctly, to confirm use of ANGLE it should display a window with a green background and a circular white mouse cursor. If ANGLE isn't in use then you'll get a red background and the mouse cursor (e.g. MacOS). You should never get a blank window.

One PC that has a problem is running Windows 7 32-bit Home Premium SP1 and has Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3600 Series (Atom N2800).

**test.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Test

QT += qml quick

SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->connect(view->engine(), SIGNAL(quit()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    view->setSource((QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml"))));
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**qml.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qml/main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**qml/main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Rectangle {
    id: root

    width: 600
    height: 400
    color:  (OpenGLInfo.renderableType == OpenGLInfo.Unspecified?
                 '#333': (OpenGLInfo.renderableType == OpenGLInfo.OpenGL?
                              '#c00': '#0c0'))

    MouseArea {
        id: mainMouseArea

        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onPositionChanged: mousePointer.position = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: mousePointer
        property point position: Qt.point(-1000,-1000)

        width: 60
        height: width
        radius: width / 2
        x: position.x - width / 2
        y: position.y - height / 2
        color: "white"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that the latest GPU driver from Intel is installed. The GPU is quite old, so maybe it is just not working with ANGLE due to faulty drivers. In this case Qt can detect this and switch to software rendering, but only if you **do not** force Qt to use ANGLE. Also, you can enable Qt platform abstraction (qpa) logging by setting the `QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.gl=true` environment variable, which will log quite a bit of useful information regarding the rendering backend.

Here are a few things you can try:

- Make sure to deploy the needed dll files: `libGLESv2.dll`, `d3dcompiler47.dll` (the latest available from the Windows SDK), `libEGL.dll` and also `opengl32sw.dll` (for software rendering). The easiest way is to do this is to just use `windeployqt`.
- Use the `qtdiag` binary to figure out which rendering backend Qt uses (when not forced to ANGLE).
- Experiment with the `QT_OPENGL` (see [Qt5 Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers)) and `QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM` environment variables (see [Qt5 Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers)).
- Check if the GPU in question is [blacklisted by Qt](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/plugins/platforms/windows/openglblacklists/default.json). It may be blacklisted for the ANGLE and/or OpenGL backend. The device id and driver version may be obtained by using `qtdiag` with enabled qpa logging (see above).

Comment: It's interesting you say the GPU may not be working with ANGLE. I know that some GPUs don't work with native/desktop but I hadn't been aware that there could be problems with ANGLE.
I shall try enabling qpa - do I set the environment variable using QProcessEnvironment in main.cpp or can it be done in the .pro?

Comment: You can do it either globally (Control Panel -> System), in your cmd prompt (`set QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.gl=true`) before running the executable or via the Qt Creator `run` settings. Using QProcessEnvironment or any other programmatic way is unfortunately too late.

Comment: Thanks. Just had the chance to retest on a problem PC. I'd already made sure it had up-to-date drivers, so this time I tested OpenGL software rendering and this sorted the problem. Sweet.

Comment: Here's a relevant new Qt blog article about OpenGL and QtQuick published 18 Jan 2017: [Which OpenGL implementation is my Qt Quick app using today?](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/18/opengl-implementation-qt-quick-app-using-today/)